# How to propagate nested error in Q .then() callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, q

I feel like this should be easy, but I've been struggling for a while on it.

I have code that looks like this (obviously this is a simplified example).

```
getPromise(param1, param2)
.then(function (results) {
    // do something that causes an error:
    var err1 = new Error()
    throw err1;
})
.then(function (results) {
    getAnotherPromise(param1)
    .then(function (res) {
        // do something else that might cause an error:
        var err2 = new Error()
        throw err2;
    })
})
.then(function (results) {
   // deal with the results of above code
})
.fail(function (error) {
   // handle error
})
```

The issue is that `err2` never causes the `.fail` handler to be called. `err1` is dealt with as expected, but `err2` just disappears. I've tried adding another `.fail` handler after the `.then` responsible for generating `err2` that just re-throws `err2`, but that doesn't change anything.

How can I write one error handler that deals with both `err1` and `err2`?

Comment: `Q` can't handle nested promise unless you `return` it.

Comment: Wow. That was easy. If you post that as an answer, I'm happy to accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Q` can't handle nested promise unless you `return` it. So, your code should look like this:

```
getPromise(param1, param2).then(function (results) {
  // do something that causes an error:
  throw new Error('error 1');
}).then(function (results) {
  return getAnotherPromise(param1).then(function (res) {
    // do something else that might cause an error:
    throw new Error('error 2');
  })
}).then(function (results) {
  // deal with the results of above code
}).fail(function (error) {
  // handle error
})
```

Actually, promise values are propogated as well as errors, so you may write your code in the following way:

```
getPromise(param1, param2).then(function (results) {
  // do something that causes an error:
  throw new Error('error 1');
}).then(function (results) {
  return getAnotherPromise(param1)
}).then(function (res) {
  // do something else that might cause an error:
  throw new Error('error 2');
}).then(function (results) {
  // deal with the results of above code
}).fail(function (error) {
  // handle error
})
```